# How do I randomly move objects in a maze using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, pacman

This is a code for Pac-Man. I already have a moving Pac-man and the collision w/ the ghosts, but I don't know how to make them randomly move on the map. I don't need them to chase the Pac-Man, just to slide randomly through the map and change direction when they hit on the wall. I also wanted to know how could I make Pac-Man die when he collides w/ a ghost.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 560))
jogo = True


class Tabuleiro:
    def __init__(self, tela, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tela = tela
        self.maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

    def show(self):
        for col in range(20):
            for lin in range(11):
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 1:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 255), rect=[self.x + col * 50, self.y + lin * 50, 50, 50])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 2:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50 + 12, self.y + lin * 50 + 12, 25, 25])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 3:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 0, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50 + 12, self.y + lin * 50 + 12, 25, 25])

    def findFirst(self, number):
        for row, rowlist in enumerate(self.maze):
            for col, cell in enumerate(rowlist):
                if cell == number:
                    return row, col
        return None, None

    def testIndex(self, row, col):
        if row == None or col == None:
            return False
        if 0 <= row < len(self.maze) and 0 <= col < len(self.maze[row]):
            return True
        return False

    def isFieldEqual(self, row, col, number):
        if self.testIndex(row, col):
            return self.maze[row][col] == number
        return False

    def swapFileds(self, row1, col1, row2, col2):
        if self.testIndex(row1, col1) and self.testIndex(row2, col2):
            self.maze[row1][col1], self.maze[row2][col2] = self.maze[row2][col2], self.maze[row1][col1]


maze = Tabuleiro(tela, 10, 10)

while jogo:

    row, col = maze.findFirst(2)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jogo = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row, col - 1, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col - 1, row, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row, col + 1, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col + 1, row, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row - 1, col, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col, row - 1, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row + 1, col, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row + 1, col, row, col)

    tela.fill(0)
    maze.show()
    pygame.display.update()
```

It's for a school project, so it doesn't have to be so complex. Thank you!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: There's a really great analysis of Pac-man's ghost movements: https://gameinternals.com/understanding-pac-man-ghost-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a method that can find all field with a specific `number` in the grid:

```py
class Tabuleiro:
    # [...]

    def findAll(self, number):
        result = []
        for row, rowlist in enumerate(self.maze):
            for col, cell in enumerate(rowlist):
                if cell == number:
                    result.append((row, col))
        return result
```

Find all the neighboring positions that can be move to. Use `random.choice()` to select a random position:

```py
while jogo:
    # [...]

    for row, col in maze.findAll(3):
        new_pos = [(row-1, col), (row+1, col), (row, col-1), (row, col+1)]
        new_pos = [(r, c) for r, c in new_pos if maze.isFieldEqual(r, c, 0)]
        if new_pos:
            new_row, new_col = random.choice(new_pos)
            maze.swapFileds(row, col, new_row, new_col)
```

Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to return the number of milliseconds since [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) was called. Set the time for the first move of the enemy. When the time exceeds move the enemy and set the time for the next move:

```py
next_move_time = 0
jogo = True
while jogo:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # [...]

    if next_move_time < current_time:
        next_move_time = current_time + 500 # 500 milliseconds = 0.5 seconds
        for row, col in maze.findAll(3):
            # [...]
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
tela = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 560))

class Tabuleiro:
    def __init__(self, tela, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tela = tela
        self.maze = [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

    def show(self):
        for col in range(20):
            for lin in range(11):
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 1:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 255), rect=[self.x + col * 50, self.y + lin * 50, 50, 50])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 2:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 255, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50 + 12, self.y + lin * 50 + 12, 25, 25])
                if self.maze[lin][col] == 3:
                    self.tela.fill((255, 0, 0), rect=[self.x + col * 50 + 12, self.y + lin * 50 + 12, 25, 25])

    def findFirst(self, number):
        for row, rowlist in enumerate(self.maze):
            for col, cell in enumerate(rowlist):
                if cell == number:
                    return row, col
        return None, None

    def findAll(self, number):
        result = []
        for row, rowlist in enumerate(self.maze):
            for col, cell in enumerate(rowlist):
                if cell == number:
                    result.append((row, col))
        return result

    def testIndex(self, row, col):
        if row == None or col == None:
            return False
        if 0 <= row < len(self.maze) and 0 <= col < len(self.maze[row]):
            return True
        return False

    def isFieldEqual(self, row, col, number):
        if self.testIndex(row, col):
            return self.maze[row][col] == number
        return False 
    
    def swapFileds(self, row1, col1, row2, col2):
        if self.testIndex(row1, col1) and self.testIndex(row2, col2):
            self.maze[row1][col1], self.maze[row2][col2] = self.maze[row2][col2], self.maze[row1][col1]


maze = Tabuleiro(tela, 10, 10)

next_move_time = 0
jogo = True
while jogo:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    row, col = maze.findFirst(2)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            jogo = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row, col-1, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col-1, row, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row, col+1, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col+1, row, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row-1, col, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row, col, row-1, col)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                if maze.isFieldEqual(row+1, col, 0):
                    maze.swapFileds(row+1, col, row, col)

    if next_move_time < current_time:
        next_move_time = current_time + 500 # 500 milliseconds = 0.5 seconds
        for row, col in maze.findAll(3):
            new_pos = [(row-1, col), (row+1, col), (row, col-1), (row, col+1)]
            new_pos = [(r, c) for r, c in new_pos if maze.isFieldEqual(r, c, 0)]
            if new_pos:
                new_row, new_col = random.choice(new_pos)
                maze.swapFileds(row, col, new_row, new_col)


    tela.fill(0)
    maze.show()
    pygame.display.update()
```